# Usage of HTTPRequest APIs for Server side app

Tags: dart, httprequest

Below chunk of code seems to require dart:io.

```
HttpRequest.getString(uri).then(onDataLoaded);
```

The App that is being designed requires to make HttpRequests to fetch metadata and build up a HTML page.  But when the below is executed, an error related to dart:io of not being availble in Dartium is output on console.

Error as below 
The built-in library 'dart:io' is not available on Dartium.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much code to see what you are actually doing.

In the browser you need to import `import 'dart:html';` and use the `HttpRequest` class from there.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/ for sample usage

Comment: Thanks, @GökhanBarışAker !  I was looking for such an example.

Comment: The below imports are already in                                                                  import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io';

Comment: You can't use `import 'dart:io';` in a browser app. You have to remove that from your code.